# comparing two text files and extracting text in python

Tags: python, file

I have two text files, one of them contains list of ids with numbers, and the other one contains list of ids with text. I want to compare two files, and for the lines having the same id print the text inside parentheses. This is what I have so file:

```
import fileinput
import sys

def clean(file1):
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file1: #file ppx
        for line in file1:
            words=line.split()
            id1=words[-1]
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as file2: #file ids
        for line in file2:
            words2=line.split() 
            id2=words2[0]
    for line in file1:
        if id1==id2[0]:
            text=s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]
    print text
```

The first file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/PCU6f7vz
The second file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Y2F3gkQv

But it does not work. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Could you expand on *"does not work"* with a [mcve]?

Comment: I have to agree. Without any further information and a working example, this is hard to understand.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the fact you have 3 loops when you should have one.

Comment: Ofcourse is not working when you have id1 and id2 variables declared in for loop scopes, and they are available only there. Outside of that they don't exist. It would be useful to provide us link to your files so we can try

Comment: Oh, for pity's... how are we supposed to read that? Please **[edit] the question.**

Comment: You can still edit your question and post the two files in a nicely formatted way. Maybe in a box for each file or so.

Comment: Or you can use pastebin.com and send us URLs to files.

Comment: There are non-ASCII characters in the strings. Thats the problem... but I don't actually know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def clean(file1):
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file1:
        file1_lines = file1.readlines()
        id1 = [line.strip().split() for line in file1_lines]
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as file2:
        file2_lines = file2.readlines()
        id2 = [line.strip().split() for line in file2_lines]
        id2_dict = {i[-1]:i[:-1] for i in id2}
    #You can print id2_dict and id1.
    #print id2_idct,
    #print id1
    for index, line in enumerate(file1_lines):
        id1 = id1[index].strip("(").strip(")")
        if id1 in id2_dict:
            text = line[line.find("(")+1:line.find(")")]
            print text
    #or:
    #text_lines = [line[line.find("(")+1:line.find(")")] for index, line in enumerate(file1_lines) if id1 in id2_dict]
    #print text_lines
```

I don't know your mind about the output of programming, so I just think you wanted to get text_lines

Answer (score 0):

`file1` is an iterator that is exhausted after all the lines in the file have been read (which will happen during the first `for` loop). Therefore, the following loop

```
for line in file1:
```

will never run. But even if it did, the condition

```
    if id1==id2[0]:
```

will never be true because you're comparing the entire `id1` to the first character of `id2`. Furthermore, you'd be doing exactly the same comparison over and over again since those variables aren't even connected to the iterable.

And in your first two loops, you're constantly overwriting the exact same variables.

I think you need to read up on Python basics, especially the chapter on loops in the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)...

Comment: import fileinput
import sys
id1dict={}
id2dict={}

with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as file2: #file ids
 for line in file2:
  words2=line.split() 
  id2=words2[0]
  id2dict[id2]=[words2]
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file1: #file ppx
 for line in file1:
  words=line.split()
  id1=words[-1]
  id1dict[id1]=[words]
 for line in file1:
  if id1==id2[0]:
   text=(''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, file1)))
   print text


   print text

I changed the code using dictionnaries but i still can not get anything printed. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To compare the same lines(line no) in the two files:

```
 file1 = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
 file2 = open(sys.argv[2], "r")
 for line1, line2 in file1,file2:
     if(line1.split()[-1] == line2.split()[0]):
          print line1 # use regex to extract the infromation needed

 file1.close()
 file2.close()
```

Make sure to close the files after use.